# Why doesn't Jackson XML deserialization respect any annotations?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I've been reading tutorials about Jackson XML deserialization ([#1](https://stackify.com/java-xml-jackson/), [#2](https://dzone.com/articles/solving-the-xml-problem-with-jackson)). I tried to follow along with examples by writing some java code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper;

public class JacksonDemo {
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"age", "id", "name"})
    public static class Person {
        @JsonProperty("_id")
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public int age;
        @JsonIgnore
        public String note;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        Person value = new Person();
        value.age = 4;
        value.id = "12345";
        value.name = "George";
        value.note = "Invalid";
        String s = mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

According to the tutorials, this should result in the following  output:

```
<Person><age>4</age><_id>12345</_id><name>George</name></Person>
```

However, it instead results in the following errant output:

```
<Person><id>12345</id><name>George</name><age>4</age><note>Invalid</note></Person>
```

The properties are in the incorrect order, the "id" field has the incorrect XML element, and the "note" field is incorrectly included. Supposedly, the various java annotations should change Jackson's behavior but it seems like all annotations are being ignored. Does anybody know why this is?

This is with jackson-xml-databind 0.6.2, jackson-annotations 2.6.0, and jackson 2.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jackson-xml-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/jackson-xml-databind) in version `0.6.2` was released on `Nov 11, 2011`. In linked articles there is a suggestion to use `jackson-dataformat-xml` library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The newest version is `2.9.8` and I suggest to use it. Below you can find `Maven` dependencies for which your example should work as expected:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version.core}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version.core}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version.core}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version.core}</version>
</dependency>
```

where `jackson.version.core` is `2.9.8`.

Comment: I was surprised when the XML parsing library was 8 years old. This explains everything, thank you!